# Issue with complete.cases: invalid 'type' (list) of argument

Tags: r

I'm getting the following error:

> Error in complete.cases(dt) : invalid 'type' (list) of argument

Never had this message before when using `complete.cases` on a data frame.

A call to `class(dt)` returns `data.frame`, so no problem there.

`dt` is relatively big -- 800,000 obs of 90 variables.

Similar operations on other data frames there are no problems.

Anyone knows what could be the problem?

Comment: Please read [how to make a great reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Also, try doing a `str(dt)`. If one of your columns contains `list` objects, `complete.cases` won't work.

Comment: @hrbrmstr please add this comment as an answer. I came across the same issue, and as you pointed out, I had list objects in data.frame.

Answer (score 5):

I also encountered the same issue. As @hrbrmstr correctly pointed out, the data.frame has list objects. In my case it was a data.frame of lists.
I converted the data.frame of lists into an actual data frame using the following command:

```
DF <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(DF), nrow=nrow(DF)),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Using complete.cases on this worked out.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and @hrbrmstr's comment on the original question was a great help. Posting the answer with code so that anyone who stumbled upon this question may benefit from it.

The dataset in question, `x`, has one or more variable of type list, leading to the error message:

> Error in complete.cases(x) : invalid 'type' (list) of argument

Usually, you would get a quick preview of the variable types from a data frame using `str()`. However, in my case I have a data frame of 2,431 variables (long and wide dataframe) so using `str()` is of limited use there. Instead, I use the handy  `sapply()` code to get a table of all classes present in my data frame:

```
table(as.character(sapply(x, class)))
# output:
c("ordered", "factor")      character         list         logical          numeric 
             1                   69            1            2225              136
```

Notice there is a variable of type `list` in our data frame.

---

### Solution

In the following code snippet, we identify any variables that are of the `list` type and remove it from `x`. We use `table()` again to verify that our data frame now no longer contain any list variables:

```
is_list <- sapply(x, is.list)
x <- x[, !is_list]
table(as.character(sapply(x, class)))
```

Proceed to apply `complete.cases()`:

```
x <- x[complete.cases(x), ]
```

Comment: Please make it reproducible, otherwise it is same as existing answer and comments.

Answer (score 0):

Same error happened to me. The problem was that one of the `data.frame`s was actually an `sf` object. I had to remove the geometry of it with `st_drop_geometry` to convert it to a regular `data.frame`.